# Why does Django Celery task is showing a "attribute error"?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, celery

When I ran the below code, Django is throwing a wrapper error the error code is shown below

**Error Message:**

> AttributeError: 'method-wrapper' object has no attribute '**module**'

```
Models.py
class PatientMasters(models.Model):
    patient_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    patient_n_key = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, unique=True)
    centre_master_short_name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=33)
    centre_master_id = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=15)
    pid_no = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    aadhar_number = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_registration = models.BigIntegerField()
    patient_name = models.CharField(max_length=45,blank=False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=45,blank=False)
    patient_category = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'patient_masters'

@receiver(post_save, sender=PatientMasters)
def generate_pat_unique_key(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
   """
       Generate unique n_key as an combination of primary key and centre_master_id
   """
   post_save.disconnect(generate_pat_unique_key, sender=PatientMasters)
   instance.patient_n_key = "{}-pat-{}".format(instance.centre_master_short_name, instance.patient_id)
   instance.save()
   post_save.connect(generate_pat_unique_key, sender=PatientMasters)


Views.py

class PatientMastersviewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=models.PatientMasters.objects.all()
    serializer_class=serializers1.PatientMastersserializer
    lookup_field = 'patient_n_key'
    tasks.PatientMastersviewset.delay()


tasks.py
@app.task
class PatientMastersviewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=models.PatientMasters.objects.all()
    serializer_class=serializers1.PatientMastersserializer
    lookup_field = 'patient_n_key'
```

Comment: Why have you used a viewset as a Celery task? That doesn't make any sense. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I have a dashboard page which takes data from 10 different urls its taking too much time load the data i want to speed it up how can i achieve

Answer (score 0):

I can make 2 answer :

1. Maybe you want to add a `self` somewhere in `tasks.py`:

`@app.task(bind=True)`

```
def patient_masters_viewset_task(self):
    queryset = models.PatientMasters.objects.all()
```

2. You prefer a LazyLoading Approach that will retrieve what you want in an ordely approach (sync/await, Promise... in js), and that not the right place to ask :)